# Is there any way to make our applet to receive all SELECT APDU commands?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

As far as you know, Card Manager (~ Security Domain) is the entity that is responsible for handling SELECT APDU commands. I need an applet to receive all the APDU commands (including SELECT APDU Commands). In the other words I need my applet to be SELECTED by default and **always selected**.

I know that I can make my applet, the "default selected" applet, but is there any way to make it "always selected" to make it receive all the APDU commands?

I guess the only way to do that is to take advantage of Delegated Management or making my applet a Security Domain. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is probably not possible. you will never be able to overrule the select command as this behaviour is a core part of the JCRE spec and there will always be the card manager selectable by its AID. Some card manufacturers have possibilities to disable the card manager but this is proprietary.

edit: the select command not possible to overrule is:

- class 0x00 (or any logical channel)
- ins 0xA4
- p1 0x04
- p2 variable
- lc+data referencing an AID or partial AID select if allowed by the chip manufacturer

Comment: I have an applet that implements the Select command (P1=04). In case the applet is selected, the applet receives all select commands except the ones that includes an DF AID that matches an applet AID. In this case the CardManager handles it and deselects my applet and selects the new one. So it is possible to handle select, but be aware that your select data doesn't match with any applet AID installed in your card.

Comment: well this conflicts with the question, because as he stated he wants every select apdu to be handled by the applet. it is very obvious you can answer to some select commands though

Comment: Is `SELECT APDU` command the only command that I can't overrule? Or `MANAGE CHANNEL` APDU command is like it too?